# How to align this particular div image and content overflow

Tags: html, css

[image]

Image and content how to align in this picture followed by content.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: sir i dont know how to write this div with image alignment.

Comment: Use `float` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owqWXg

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
}

.imgContainer {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}

.imgContainer p {
  margin: 0;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam nisi vitae ultrices viverra. Donec egestas eu odio vitae vehicula. Donec vitae lacinia leo. Mauris in libero purus.
  <div class="imgContainer"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x50">
    <p class="imageNote">Note under img</p>
  </div>Cras interdum sapien tortor, non pretium tellus rhoncus quis. Nunc dapibus dignissim dolor ut bibendum. Curabitur in arcu consectetur, dignissim est eu, porta velit. In luctus purus eget elit placerat tempor. Quisque id ante sit amet lacus tincidunt
  lacinia.
</div>
```